# Student seeking help for SSRS filter

Tags: sql, reporting-services, reporting

I'm using SSRS. I'm trying to setup a filter that functions as a phone number search. If there is no phone number, it could be null and otherwise search entered phone number. I've attached my code below.

```
declare @phonein varchar (50)
set @phonein = ''

select d.MethodTitle, d.Active, d.ReferralMethodID, s.TollFreePhoneID, s.Phone, s.AdminModifyDateTime
from tReferralMethod as d
inner join tTollFreePhone
as s
on s.ReferralMethodID = d.ReferralMethodID

where s.phone = @phonein
```

I'm at a standstill at the last line, I think.

Comment: First, you don't `declare` input parameters in SSRS queries - they are passed in automatically by the query engine.  Second, are you saying that an empty input parameter would give all records where phone number is null?

Comment: yes to your second question @DStanley. Thanks for the first part too, appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find records with a null phone number using a null parameter value, use

```
where (@phonein IS NULL and s.phone IS NULL) OR (s.phone = @phonein)
```